# Custom export to word from KendoUI editor saved to DB- screenshots are not getting exported to word

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, ms-word, kendo-asp.net-mvc, export-to-word

Hello i have question like i was using kendo UI editor 
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/editor/import-export and save the details to DB the content of this UI editor like screenshots text entered data etc. while retriving and showing in UI i was able to show by decoding. but i have requierement like need to export to word.. when i want export the content from DB to Word am decoding it again and exporting but screenshots are not getting exported to word. please help looking for solution

here is the code:

```
  public void ExporttoHtml(int no)
    {

        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";

        #region HtmlDesign
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + no + ".doc");
        StringBuilder bodycontent = new StringBuilder("");
        GetContentToExporttoWord(bodycontent, no);
        #endregion



        #region Rendering 
        HttpContext.Response.Write(bodycontent);
        HttpContext.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        #endregion
    }
    private void GetContentToExporttoWord(StringBuilder bodycontent, int no)
    {
        Exportdetail objecdet = GetDetailsfromDB(no);

        bodycontent.Append(@"<html 
                            xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' 
                            xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
                            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
                            <head><title></title>



                         </head>
       <body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>");
        bodycontent.Append("<h2><table valign = 'middle' width = '100%' Border = '0' Cellpadding = '2' Cellspacing = '2'><tr>");
        bodycontent.Append("<div class='Section1'>");
        bodycontent.Append("<table valign = 'middle' width = '100% ' Border = '0' Cellpadding = '2' Cellspacing = '2' class='page-break-after:always'>");

        bodycontent.Append("<td colspan='2'><b><span style=' width:100px;'>Request Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></b> " + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(objecdet.EditorData + "</td></tr></div>"));
    }

    public class Exportdetail
    {
        public string EditorData { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt.

Comment: @CarstenFranke Franke posted the code pls help out